# Prove that countable intersection/union of zero/cozero sets is a zero/cozero set.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, general-topology, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

> **Definition**
>
> A subset $Z$ of a topological space $X$ is a zero-set if there exist a continuous real valued function $f:X\rightarrow\Bbb R$ such that
> $$
> Z=f^{-1}[0]
> $$
> So we say that a subset $Z^C$ of $X$ is cozero-set if $X\setminus Z^C$ is zero-set.

So to follow I tried to prove that the countable intersection/union of zero/cozero sets is a zero/cozero sets so that on this purpose let be
$$
\mathcal Z:=\big\{Z_n:n\in\Bbb N\big\}\quad\text{and}\quad\mathcal Z^C:=\big\{Z_n^C:n\in\Bbb N\big\}
$$
two countable collection of zero and cozero sets resectively.

> First of all if $f_n$ is for each $n\in\Bbb N$ a continuous real valued function in $X$ such that
> $$
> f_n(x)=0
> $$
> for any $x\in X$ then we observe that without loss of generality we can suppose that the inequality
> $$
> \begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq:simple}
> |f_n(x)|<\frac 12
> \end{equation}
> $$
> holds for any $x\in X$ because the function
> $$
> \varphi:\Bbb R\ni y\to \frac{|y|}{2\big(|y|+1\big)}\in\Bbb R
> $$
> is continuous and such that
> $$
> \big|\varphi(y)\big|\le\frac 12
> $$
> for any $y\in\Bbb R$ so that finally $\varphi\circ f_n$ is a continuous real valued function in $X$ satisfying the inequality \eqref{eq:simple} and such that
> $$
> \big(\varphi\circ f_n\big)(x)=0
> $$
> for any $x\in Z_n$. So we observe that the inequality
> $$
> \Big|\big(f_n(x)\big)^n\Big|=\big|f(x)\big|^n\le\frac 1{2^n}
> $$
> holds for each $n\in\Bbb N$ and for each $x\in X$ so that the serie
> $$
> f:=\sum_{n\in\omega}f_n^n
> $$
> totally converges to a continuous function (remember that $f_n$ is for any $n\in\omega$ cotinuous!) $f$ so that we let to prove that
> $$
> Z_f=\bigcap_{n\in\omega}Z_n
> $$
> So we observe that the identity
> $$
> f(x)=\sum_{n\in\omega}\big(f_n(x)\big)^n=\sum_{n\in\omega}0=0
> $$
> holds clearly for any $n\in\omega$ when $x\in\bigcap_{n\in\omega}Z_n$ so that
> $$
> \bigcap_{n\in\omega}Z_n\subseteq Z_f
> $$
> After all, if $x_0\notin\bigcap_{n\in\omega}Z_n$ then the set
> $$
> Z_x:=\{n\in\omega:x\notin Z_n\}
> $$
> is nonempty and thus the infimum of the set
> $$
> F_0:=\big\{f_n(x_0):n\in\omega\big\}
> $$
> is **positive** (remember that $f_n$ is for each $n\in\omega$ positive definite!) and strictly less then $1$, that is there exists $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ such that
> $$
> \epsilon^n\le\big(f_n(x)\big)^n
> $$
> for any $n\in\omega$ and thus such that
> $$
> 0<\frac 1{1-\epsilon}=\sum_{n\in\omega}\epsilon^n\le\sum_{n\in\omega}\big(f_n(x)\big)^n=f(x)
> $$
> so that we conclude that
> $$
> X\setminus\bigcap_{n\in\omega}Z_n\subseteq X\setminus Z_f
> $$
> that is
> $$
> Z_f\subseteq\bigcap_{n\in\omega}Z_n
> $$
> So we proved that the countable intersection of zero sets is a zero set. Now $X\setminus Z_n^C$ is for each $n\in\Bbb N$ a zero set so that also the intersecion $\bigcap_{n\in\omega}\big(X\setminus Z_n^C\big)$ is a zero set and thus observing that
> $$
> \bigcup_{n\in\omega}Z^C_n=X\setminus\Biggl(X\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\omega}Z^C_n\Biggl)=X\setminus\bigcap_{n\in\omega}\big(X\setminus Z_n^C\big)
> $$
> we conclude that the countable union of cozero sets is a cozero set.

So I ask if the proof I gave are correct and in particular I ask if the totally convergent and infimum argumens are well applied: could someone help me, please?

Comment: Other names for zero set and co-zero set are functionally closed set and functionally open set.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Oh, okay. Only a question: which is the most used name?

Comment: I dk which is more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The topological generalization of the classical $\epsilon$-$\delta$ statement that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous at a point $x\in\Bbb R$ is:

The function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous at $x\in X$ iff for every open $V$ of $Y$ such that $f(x)\in V,$ there exists an open $U$ of $X$ with $x\in U,$ such that the image $f[U]\subset V.$

Then we have: $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $f$ is continuous at each $x\in X.$

Now in your work, for $m\in\omega$ let $g_m(x)=\sum_{n\le m}(f_n(x))^n.$ Then each  $g_m$ is continuous, and $g_m$ converges uniformly to $f.$ Therefore $f$ is continuous.

Proof: Let $x\in X$ and let $V$ be an open subset of $\Bbb R$ with $f(x)\in V.$ Take $r>0$ such that $(-r+f(x),r+f(x))\subset V.$ Take $m\in\omega$ large enough that $\forall x'\in X\,(|f(x')-g_m(x')|<r/3).$ Take an open $U$ in $X$ with $x\in U,$ such that $g_m[U]\subset (-r/3+f(x),r/3+f(x)).$ Now if $x'\in U$ then $$|f(x')-f(x)|\le |f(x')-g_m(x')|+|g_m(x')-g_m(x)|+|g_m(x)-f(x)|<$$ $$<r/3+r/3+r/3=r$$ implying $f(x')\in V.$ So $f$ is continuous at $x.$

Comment: Hi! First of all thanks for the answer. However I do not see hos take $m\in\omega$ large enought that $$|f(x')-g_m(x')|<\frac r 3$$ holds for all $x'\in X$: so could you show this to me, please? Forgive the bother.

Comment: If $2^{-m}<r/3$  then $|f(x')-g_m(x')|=\sum_{n>m}(f_n(x'))^n\le \sum_{n>m}2^{-n}=2^{-m}<r/3.$

Comment: @DanielWainflet Okay, all clear now: question upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance!

Comment: What you called totally convergent is called uniformly convergent.

Comment: Ah, I do not know. My text (in Italian) says that a serie of functions $\sum_{k\in\omega} f_k$ is totally convergent if there exists a convergent not negative serie $\sum_{k\in\omega}M_k$ such that $|f_ k(x)|\le M_k$ for any $x\in X$ wheres it says that $\sum_{k\in\omega}f_k$ is con uniformly convergtent if it converges with respect uniform topology.

Comment: So is still my proof correct with respect these definitions?

Comment: Yes  Your proof is correct.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your check. :)